# KnockoutJS Select Options and Selected Value

Tags: knockout.js

Similar question as: [Select element's initial value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516089/knockoutjs-select-initial-value)

I'm having an issue setting the initial value of the select element. I basically have a list of seed data coming in from the server to populate the drop down list, and I want the selected value to represent what should be selected from the entity.

Because the data model's selected value doesn't equal the object reference in the seed data, nothing is selected.

Right now, I'm looping through each entity, finding the correct selected value, setting that equal to the seed data's equivalent, then Knockout knows how to wire it up.

Is there a more elegant solution that this? I fiddled a simplified example with more details... http://jsfiddle.net/hbrYM/14/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As you correctly guessed the selectedValue reference doesn't match so KO doesn't select that item. The way to get this to work is to not save the complex object in the selected value and instead select the ID, as a primitive type equality can succeed and the correct value is selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/VLTFB/3/

You'll need to use the optionsValue option on the options binding (if that makes sense :)

```
<select data-bind="options: seedData,
                    optionsText: 'firstName',
                    optionsValue: 'ID',
                    value: data.selectedValue">
```

**EDIT**

As discussed you can reselect the correct item with a computed (untested).

```
vm.currentlySelected = ko.computed(function () { 
   for (var i = 0; i < this.seedData().length; i += 1) {
       var data = this.seedData()[i];
       if (data.ID === this.selectedValue()) {
           return data;
       }
   }
   return null;
}, vm);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for replying, it makes sense. I currently send back the object (not just the ID) which then gets deserialized and persisted. I was really hoping there was a way to "instruct" KO how to wire this up because I have so many different selects in this particular UI...

Comment: You can still send back the object quite easily just when the select data from the server comes in, just send the id. When you need to send a new selected back simply write a computed that retreives the currently selected object (see edit). It's actually leaner to do it this way, you already have the seed data so why bother sending all that extra info again.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I will take a look at using that approach.

Comment: Seems like a bug to me... You'd expect the `value` binding should match against `optionsValue` key rather than needing the entire object. If only a certain key is saved, only a certain key should be matched.

Comment: ko select binding is really missing some kind of "object reference management" for that. Sometimes we want the optionValue to be set to a particular property so it can be sent back to the server naturally (using form.submit() without modification for example), but still be able to handle the currently selected object to do javascript work with it, which cannot be done currently with KO.

Comment: In case it isn't clear, the optionsValue needs to be a number. if you try to set it to a string value, it won't bind and you'll have an empty value attribute.

Comment: @MrBoJangles: this is utterly wrong. It may be any primitive.

Comment: @ZzZombo I've been away from Knockout for some time so I'll have to defer to your correction. I must have arrived at the wrong conclusion when I was last working on a KO project.

Comment: Mr Bojangles ... Thank you this helped. Data types is important. Looks like passing in an array of strings will not select the options on an array of ints, and vice versa.

Comment: Fantastic.... for some reason I was forced to use  `value: $data.selectedValue` instead of just `value:selectedValue`. Would not work otherwise. BTW, Yours probably should say `value: $data.selectedValue`, not `value: data.selectedValue`