# How to bind dropdown to property of selected item using Knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

I want to select one item in a list. This opens up a dropdown where I can change one of the properties of the selected item. The dropdown should preselect the current value of the property.

However, my implementation is not working as I expected. Instead of the dropdown showing the items value, it's the other way around. The item's property is updated to the selected value in the dropdown.

Why is this not working as I expected and how can it be changed to work that way?

#### Model

```
Scoring = (function () {
    function Scoring(valuePredefined) {
        var self = this;
        self.valuePredefined = ko.observable(valuePredefined);
    }

    return Scoring;
})();
```

#### ViewModel

```
AdjustmentEditViewModel = (function ($) {
    function AdjustmentEditViewModel() {
        var self = this;

        self.selectedScoring = ko.observable();

        var scorings = [new Scoring({ name: "Type 1" }), new Scoring({ name: "Type 2" })];
        self.scorings = ko.observableArray(scorings);

        self.getScoringName = function (scoring) {
            return scoring.valuePredefined().name;
        };

        self.predefinedValues = [{ name: "Type 1" }, { name: "Type 2" }];
    }

    return AdjustmentEditViewModel;
})(jQuery);
```

#### View

```
<select data-bind="options: scorings, value: selectedScoring, optionsText: function (item) { return getScoringName(item); }" size="5"></select>
<!-- ko if: selectedScoring -->
<select data-bind="options: predefinedValues, value: selectedScoring().valuePredefined, optionsText: function (item) { return item.name; }"></select>
<!-- /ko -->
```

#### Full source

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="knockout-3.1.0.js"></script>
    <script>
        Scoring = (function () {
            function Scoring(valuePredefined) {
                var self = this;
                self.valuePredefined = ko.observable(valuePredefined);
            }

            return Scoring;
        })();

        AdjustmentEditViewModel = (function ($) {
            function AdjustmentEditViewModel() {
                var self = this;

                self.selectedScoring = ko.observable();

                var scorings = [new Scoring({ name: "Type 1" }), new Scoring({ name: "Type 2" })];
                self.scorings = ko.observableArray(scorings);

                self.getScoringName = function (scoring) {
                    return scoring.valuePredefined().name;
                };

                self.predefinedValues = [{ name: "Type 1" }, { name: "Type 2" }];
            }

            return AdjustmentEditViewModel;
        })(jQuery);

        $(window).load(function () {
            ko.applyBindings(new AdjustmentEditViewModel());
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select data-bind="options: scorings, value: selectedScoring, optionsText: function (item) { return getScoringName(item); }" size="5"></select>
    <!-- ko if: selectedScoring -->
    <select data-bind="options: predefinedValues, value: selectedScoring().valuePredefined, optionsText: function (item) { return item.name; }"></select>
    <!-- /ko -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out why it wasn't working, the problem was binding the dropdown to an object instead of a primitive, the same explation as this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10543590/3310842).

To solve this I chose to only represent the id in the scoring. I created a new function in the view model to get the name, used only to display it in the list, like this:

```
self.getPredefinedName = function(predefinedID) {
    var predefined = ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.predefinedValues(), function (item) {
        return item.id() == predefinedID;
    });

    if (predefined) {
        return predefined.name();
    }
};
```

Then I used this function instead of binding directly to the valuePredefined property.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding same observable to value of both dropdown instead of this take different observable properties and subscribe the first property that used in first dropdown to change the value of other dropdown.

```
     function Scoring(valuePredefined) {
           this.name = ko.observable(valuePredefined);
     }

     AdjustmentEditViewModel = (function ($) {
      function AdjustmentEditViewModel() {
       var self = this;

       self.selectedScoring = ko.observable();
       self.selectedScoring2 = ko.observable();
       self.selectedScoring.subscribe(function (newValue) {
          self.selectedScoring2(newValue.name());
       });
       self.selectedScoring2.subscribe(function (newValue) {
          self.selectedScoring().name(newValue || newValue.valuePredefined().name);
       });
       var scorings = [new Scoring("Type 1"), new Scoring("Type 2")];
       self.scorings = ko.observableArray(scorings);

       self.predefinedValues = [{
          name: "Type 1"
          }, {
          name: "Type 2"
          }];
       }

      return AdjustmentEditViewModel;
    })(jQuery);
```

[***JsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/Akhlesh/NAx3C/1/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it's not working all the way. The reason for them being the same is that i want the name of the item in the list to change when i choose another value in the dropdown.

Comment: are they dependent on each other? when you select 1st dropdown it will change 2nd dropdown and vice versa right?

Comment: Yes, selecting the first dropdown will change the selected item in the second. Selecting the second dropdown will change the name of the selected item in the first.

Comment: Are you sure?i think it will create infinite loop.

Comment: When selecting the second dropdown I only want the optionsText to change for the selected item in the first dropdown, not the value. I realize now that my example is not very clear on that point. In the real application there are severals properties that you can change, and the first dropdown displays all the properties concatenated together.