# KnockoutJS Select Dropdown not prepopulating with selected value

Tags: knockout.js

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/adNuR/2187/

```
// Template
<div  data-bind="foreach: lines">
     <p data-bind="text: item.description"></p>
     <select data-bind="value: item, options: sampleOptions, optionsText: 'description', optionsCaption: 'Please select'"></select>
</div>


// JS
var sampleOptions = [
        { description: "item 1" },
        { description: "item 2" },
        { description: "item 3" },
        { description: "item 4" }
        ];    

var Model = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.lines = ko.observableArray([
        { item: { description: "item 1" } },
        { item: { description: "item 2" } }
    ]);
};

ko.applyBindings(new Model());
```

Basically I have an object bound to a select box, but it's not selecting the selected option in the dropdown. It'll display the correct value if I data-bind the text of the selected option to another element, but I can't seem to get the select box to load with the initial preselected value no matter what I try.

Probably something trivial and stupid, but I can't seem to get it figured out... Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is probably a duplicate of this: [Select element's initial value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516089/knockoutjs-select-initial-value)

So basically you need to compare two literals to see which value should be set initially in the dropdown. It looks like it doesn't work with entire objects. A quick fix for your example would be this (updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adNuR/2189/):

```
 <select data-bind="value:item.description, options: sampleOptions, optionsValue:'description', optionsText: 'description', optionsCaption: 'Please select'"></select>
```

But you will likely want to add some proper ids to the options and compare based on those.

Comment: Yeah, the real code is much more complicated and saving dynamically generated objects with nested lists inside of them representing the possible values for other select boxes later in the form, so I really need to save the entire object and not just a literal. It turns out that's not really going to work nicely for the reasons you've mentioned so I've now just reworked it to work entirely differently and it seems to be okay. Will accept this answer though because it does solve the specific problem outlined in the fiddle :) Thanks!